# Doxygen warning if custom section is not documented

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to figure out how I can detect if a C source file contains a list of custom doxygen sections.
For instance, I want that each C source file contains:

```
/**
\section limitations Limitations
       The limitations ...

\section choices Choices
       The design choices ...
*/
```

As I use doxygen to document the code, I would like doxygen prints a warning if those sections are missing. Is it possible ?